# Concatenate two columns in pandas data frame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn

My data frame looks like -

```
state        msg              value
aa          a,b,r              .22
bb          m,b,r             1.43
cc          a,b,q              .33
dd          h,h,f              .25
```

I want my data frame looks like -

```
state        msg              value      text
aa          a,b,r              .22      a,b,r .22
bb          m,b,r             1.43      m,b,r 1.43
cc          a,b,q              .33      a,b,q .33
dd          h,h,f              .25      h,h,f .25
```

I have done -

```
df.info()

 #   Column        Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------        --------------  ----- 
 0   state         6925 non-null   object
 1   msg           6925 non-null   object
 2   value         6925 non-null   object

df['text'] = df['state'].astype(str).str.cat(df['value'], sep=' ')
```

But got this error -

```
TypeError: Concatenation requires list-likes containing only strings (or missing values). Offending values found in column mixed.
```

and no missing or null value is present.

Comment: `df['msg'].astype(str).str.cat(df['value'].astype(str), sep=' ')`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just need to change the type of the values you take from the 'value' column for concatenation. Concatenation works only on suitable data types. In your code it's string + float which will not work.
This will help you:

```
df['text'] = df['state'].astype(str).str.cat(df['value'].astype(str), sep=' ')
```